# Quoting programmatically (i.e., for macros)

Tags: common-lisp, macrodef

I would like to be able to do this:

```
(mapcar #'quote '(1 2 3 4))
```

And get this

> ('1 '2 '3 '4)

However, since QUOTE is a special form, it can not be funcalled.

I've tried to macro it up:

```
(defmacro quoter (&rest args)
  `(loop for arg in ,@args collect (quote arg)))

(quoter '(1 2 3 4 ))
```

But that gets me, as I might expect....

```
(LOOP FOR ARG IN '(1 2 3 4)
      COLLECT 'ARG)
```

Converting the input into a string and then into a  symbol from that won't work - I might have incoming forms, not just atoms.

I'm sure I'm missing something here. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will produce an expansion you want:

```
(defmacro quoter (&rest args)
   (loop for arg in args collect `(quote ,arg)))
```

...but it's unlikely that such a macro is really what you want at a higher level (unless you want just to play with macros). The expansion is not a valid list form, so the only way to use it is to call `MACROEXPAND` yourself. And if you're going to call `MACROEXPAND`, why not make it a function and call that function?

Comment: I'm mostly just playing with macros. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to transform an item to a form `(quote item)`, then you have to provide the transformation.

For example `(list 'quote item)` or

```
`(quote ,item)
```

If you use a special form or a macro inside a function, then you can use the function and pass it to something like `MAPCAR`.

```
CL-USER > (mapcar #'(lambda (item) (list 'quote item)) '(1 2 3 4))

((QUOTE 1) (QUOTE 2) (QUOTE 3) (QUOTE 4))
```

This works also if the list is replaced with a variable.

If you want to write this as macro, then you get the problem that you get source code and you need to transform it. If you have a list, then you can transform it directly. If you have for example a variable, then you can't (since you don't know the value of this variable) and you would have include the transformation into the generated source.

Example:

```
CL-USER 119 > (defmacro quoter (list)
                (list 'quote (mapcar (lambda (item) (list 'quote item))
                                     (second list))))
QUOTER

CL-USER 120 > (macroexpand '(quoter '(1 2 3 4)))
(QUOTE ((QUOTE 1) (QUOTE 2) (QUOTE 3) (QUOTE 4)))
T

CL-USER 121 > (quoter '(1 2 3 4))
((QUOTE 1) (QUOTE 2) (QUOTE 3) (QUOTE 4))
```

But now it does not know what to do with `(quoter some-variable)`. Now you can't transform a list - because it is not known. Now you would need to provide a macro expansion which would to the transformation at runtime...

Comment: The motivation is that I'm actually trying to see if I can write a fexpr facility in Common Lisp, just for fun. :-)

Comment: @PaulNathan, Common Lisp provides compiler-macros, probably the closest you can get without having to write your own code walker.

Answer (score 2):

The one-liner for this is:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) `',x) '(1 2 3 4))
```

Note the usage of quotes. I find this form useful sometime.